# Smooth edges with CurveToMesh instead of hard edges [geometry nodes]

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, smooth

I want to create an square arch using geometry nodes, but the Mesh to Curve returns a geometry without hard edges. Is this problem with geometry nodes or smoothing for lighting, and how can I make it to show hard edges with flat surface.

[image: Smooth edges]

[image: Code]

Comment: Simply apply the `Set Shade Smooth` node afterwards. Or, if that doesn't help, apply the `Split Edges` node after the grid so that you get separate edges.

Comment: So far I found EdgeSplit modifier does this, but I am still wondering why I am getting smooth result from geometry nodes.

Comment: @quellenform Thank you, Set Shade Smooth worked. Setting Split Edges modifier after geometry nodes modifier so far works the best as it keeps the inner surface smooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split edges going between the vertices with the same local (modulo) index:

[image]